# Flexbox: scale image proportionally to dynamic parent height

Tags: css, flexbox

Using flexbox, I created the following layout for a user profile page:
[image: Current result]

As you can see, the image is taller than the text it is attached to.

Instead, I am trying to make it scale exactly to the size of the text on its left: [image]

---

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.padder-wrap {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.padder-content {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
}

.whoami {
  display: flex;
}

.whoami-names {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.avatar {
  padding-left: 1em;
}


/* Decorative styles */

.padder-wrap {
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

.realname {
  font-size: 200%;
}

.nickname {
  color: #333;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.social-links {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: .3em;
}

.social-link {
  max-width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class='padder-wrap'>
  <div class='padder-content'>
    <div class='whoami'>
      <div class='whoami-names'>
        <div class='realname'>John Doe</div>
        <div class='nickname'>johndoe</div>
        <div class='social-links'>
          <a href='https://linkedin.com'>
            <svg class='social-link' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
              <rect fill="#ddd" width="100" height="100"/>
              <text fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="30" dy="10.5" font-weight="bold" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">100×100</text>
            </svg>
          </a>
          <a href='https://github.com'>
            <svg class='social-link' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
              <rect fill="#ddd" width="100" height="100"/>
              <text fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="30" dy="10.5" font-weight="bold" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">100×100</text>
            </svg>
          </a>
          <a href='https://twitter.com'>
            <svg class='social-link' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
              <rect fill="#ddd" width="100" height="100"/>
              <text fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="30" dy="10.5" font-weight="bold" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">100×100</text>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='avatar'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The current code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/x91jhp27/32/

---

**Attempts so far:**

So far I tried many different things with just the `<img>`, then the same props on a wrapping `<div>`.

For some reason it seems like the avatar container is either ignoring `height` and `max-height` or calculating them based on the viewport instead of the parent. `position: relative` did not fix that.

Using `flex-basis: 0` with `flex-grow: 1` (to make the image 0 height but allow it to grow to fill) did not work either, since the image just stays its normal size.

I can force the container to shrink via `overflow: hidden`, but for some reason the width of the container remains the same even when its height decreases. This was actually an issue even for making the desired output screenshot, since when I manually set the heights to specific pixel values the parent flexbox would not shrink (in Chrome Devtools the flexbox was much larger than the sum of its children, as if it was containing the image width directly and ignoring the avatar container). I had to manually reset the width on the background container to force it to shrink to size.

Answer (score 0):

It is always an interesting subject "how to fix height". So as your choice is to not have a fix height on your container `.whoami` which would have been the easiest way obviously.

The only way I see is to use jQuery or JS to colllect height from `.whoami-names.

So I am getting the height of each element from the block `.whoami-names` and then adding it to the `avatar` container with jQuery.

That is the "hard" part.

Then in CSS to adjust responsivity of image I just add as below:

```
.avatar {
  display:flex;
}
.avatar img{
  margin:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

DEMO:

```js
var realnameHeight = $('.realname').first().outerHeight();

var nicknameHeight = $('.nickname').first().outerHeight();

var socialLinkHeight = $('.social-links').first().outerHeight();


var totalHeightwhoamiNames  = realnameHeight + nicknameHeight + socialLinkHeight;

totalHeightwhoamiNames += 'px';


$('.avatar').first().css('height', totalHeightwhoamiNames)
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.padder-wrap {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.padder-content {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
}

.whoami {
  display: flex;
}

.whoami-names {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.avatar {
  padding-left: 1em;
  display:flex;
}
.avatar img{
  margin:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}


/* Decorative styles */

.padder-wrap {
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

.realname {
  font-size: 200%;
}

.nickname {
  color: #333;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.social-links {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: .3em;
}

.social-link {
  max-width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='padder-wrap'>
  <div class='padder-content'>
    <div class='whoami'>
      <div class='whoami-names'>
        <div class='realname'>John Doe</div>
        <div class='nickname'>johndoe</div>
        <div class='social-links'>
          <a href='https://linkedin.com'>
            <svg class='social-link' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
              <rect fill="#ddd" width="100" height="100"/>
              <text fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="30" dy="10.5" font-weight="bold" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">100×100</text>
            </svg>
          </a>
          <a href='https://github.com'>
            <svg class='social-link' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
              <rect fill="#ddd" width="100" height="100"/>
              <text fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="30" dy="10.5" font-weight="bold" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">100×100</text>
            </svg>
          </a>
          <a href='https://twitter.com'>
            <svg class='social-link' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
              <rect fill="#ddd" width="100" height="100"/>
              <text fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="30" dy="10.5" font-weight="bold" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">100×100</text>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='avatar'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```